# Error while installing binary: checksum rejected for file pact-1.63.0-linux-x86_64.tar.zip with checksum

Tags: unit-testing, pact

When we try to download from artifactory facing issue with checksum /node_modu1es/pact/node_modu1es/@pact-foundation/pact-node/standalone/pact-
1.63.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
Extracting binary from /apps/jenkins/buiid/pact_binaries/BUILD/node_modules/pact/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-node/standalone/pact-
1.63.0-1inux-x86_64.tar.gz.
(node:8471) UnhandledPromiseRejection
ror: Error while instaliing binary. Postinstalled Failed
Unexpectedly: Error: Error while
pinary: Extraction failed fo
/apps/jenkins/build/BUTL0/node noduies/pact/node modules/@pact-foundation/pact-node/standalone/pact-1.63.0-1inux-x86 64.tar.g2: Error: Error while installine binari Checksum rejected for flle 'pact-1.638-1inux x86_64.tar.gz' with checksum pact-1.63.0-1inux-x86.tar.gz checksum
at throw error (/apps/jenkins/build/workspace/CREDAPP/sc-a /BUILD/node modules/pact/no
cde-ui/CROP-
node/standalone/install.js:232:11)
Les/@pact-foundation/pact
at /apps/jenkins/build/workspace/CREDAPP/sc
modules/@pact-foundation

It should extract binary and work as expected.